# Org mode dynamic numbering of sub headings only

Tags: org-mode

In Org Mode, is it possible to dynamically number sub headings without dynamically numbering the parent headings? Example:

[image: Dynamic numbering of sub headings]

The Org Num minor mode allows you to exclude selected headings from numbering, but I want to achieve the inverse. To achieve this I tried setting `org-num-skip-unnumbered` to true, then setting the UNNUMBERED property of the parent heading to true and the UNNUMBERED property of the sub-heading to nil. This did not work.

Comment: My initial attempts to accomplish this failed: it seems that the mode is biased towards being able to eliminate the numbering of lower levels while keeping the numbering at higher levels. If nobody comes up with a solution here, you might want to post an RFE to the Org mode [mailing list](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-mailing-list.html)

Answer (score 0):

See also [org export - Org-mode do not inheriting Unnumbered property - Emacs Stack Exchange](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/68188/org-mode-do-not-inheriting-unnumbered-property/73951#73951), which is about numbering on the export side.

The code below has nothing  to do with `org-num-mode`: `org-num-mode` fontifies; that is, it changes headline numbers as and when the headline level changes.

But what you have here is a set of command `show-headline-numbers` and `hide-headline-numbers`.  If you change the headlines, the numbers won't refresh automatically, or fontification may be "off".  In that case, turn off and turn on the numbering again.

---

1. `emacs -Q`
2. Copy the following snippet to `*scratch*` buffer, and do`M-x eval-buffer`.  This will install a command `show-headline-numbers`, and bind that command to `C-c C-c`.  (This key binding is only for quick testing of the snippet)

```lisp
(require 'ox)

(defvar headline-number)

(put 'headline-number 'face 'bold)
(put 'headline-number 'headline-numbers t)

(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-b") 'do-show-headline-numbers)

(defun current-element ()
  (let* ((context (org-with-wide-buffer
                   (org-element-context)))
         (whole-tree
          (org-with-wide-buffer
           (org-element-parse-buffer))))
    (org-element-map whole-tree (org-element-type context)
      (lambda (el)
        (when (and (= (org-element-property :begin el)
                      (org-element-property :begin context)))
          el))
      nil t)))

(defun do-show-headline-numbers (level &optional data)
  (cl-letf (((symbol-function 'org-export-numbered-headline-p)
             ;; Temporariy pretend that all headlines are numbered.
             (lambda (_headline _info)
               t)))
    (let* ((data (or data (org-with-wide-buffer
                           (org-element-parse-buffer))))
           (buf (current-buffer))
           (info
            (org-export--collect-tree-properties
             data
             ;; Ignore in buffer params; use these instead
             `(:headline-levels 10 :section-numbers t)))
           (headline-numbering (org-export--collect-headline-numbering (plist-get info :parse-tree) info)))
      (cl-loop for (h . ns) in headline-numbering
               for num-ns = (length ns)
               for raw-text = (org-element-property :raw-value h)
               for beg = (org-element-property :begin h)
               for displayed-ns = (mapcar #'number-to-string ns)
               for displayed-n = (mapconcat #'identity displayed-ns ".")
               for end = (with-current-buffer buf
                           (save-excursion
                             (goto-char beg)
                             (skip-chars-forward "*")
                             (point)))
               for ov = (with-current-buffer buf
                          (when-let ((ov (cl-some
                                          (lambda (ov)
                                            (when (eq (overlay-get ov 'category) 'headline-number)
                                              ov))
                                          (overlays-at beg))))
                            (message "WARNING: Overwriting existing overlay")
                            (delete-overlay ov))
                          (make-overlay beg end))
               when (<= num-ns level)
               do
               (overlay-put ov 'display displayed-n)
               (overlay-put ov 'category 'headline-number)))))

(defun get-choices (prompt choices)
  (assoc-default (completing-read prompt choices nil t) choices))

(defun show-headline-numbers ()
  (interactive)
  (unless (eq 'headline (org-element-type (org-element-context)))
    (error "Cursor not on a headline"))
  (let* ((showp (get-choices "Operation: " '(("show" . t)
                                             ("hide" . nil))))
         (scope (when showp
                  (get-choices "Scope: " '(("buffer" . buffer)
                                           ("children" . children)
                                           ("siblings (including self)" . siblings)))))
         (n (when showp
              (read-number (format "[Number %s] Upto Depth: " (capitalize (symbol-name scope)))))))
    (cond
     (showp
      (pcase scope
        (`buffer
         (do-show-headline-numbers n))
        (`children
         (let* ((h (current-element)))
           (do-show-headline-numbers n (org-element-contents h))))
        (`siblings
         (let* ((h (current-element))
                (parent-h (org-export-get-parent-headline h)))
           (do-show-headline-numbers n parent-h)))))
     ((not showp)
      (hide-headline-numbers)))))

(defun hide-headline-numbers ()
  (interactive)
  (org-with-wide-buffer
   (remove-overlays (point-min) (point-max) 'headline-numbers t)))

(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-c") 'show-headline-numbers)
```

3. Download, and visit [`org-manual.org`](https://github.com/kjambunathan/org-mode-ox-odt/blob/0f78c19209d7dae64018868e6b9c6b6eff5471e5/doc/org-manual.org#L9).

   The buffer looks as below.  Note the absence of headline numbers.

***Default view of `org-manual.org`***

[image: Default view of org-manual.org]
4. Do `C-c C-c`, answer the prompts as follows

- `Operation` is `show`
- `Scope` is `buffer`
- `Depth` is 3

In other words, you are requesting that all headlines up to level 3 be numbered (using overlay)

This is what you will see

***Number all headlines in buffer upto level 3***

[image: Number all headlines in buffer upto level 3]

5. Do `C-c C-c`, answer the prompts as follows

- `Operation` is `hide`

  In other words, you are requesting that all headline numbers added in previous step be cleared.

You will see that all the headline numbers added in previous step are cleared.

6. Navigate to any other headline, say `Summary`, and do `C-c C-c`, answer the prompts as follows

- `Operation` is `show`
- `Scope` is `siblings (including self)`
- `Depth` is 1

In other words, you are requesting that all sibling headlines of `Summary`, and their children up to level 1 be numbered (using overlay)

This is what you will see

***Number all siblings of `Summary` up to level 1***

[image: Number all siblings up to level 1]

7. Clear the headline numbers.  Now navigate to any other headline, say `Document Structure`, and do `C-c C-c`, answer the prompts as follows

- `Operation` is `show`
- `Scope` is `children`
- `Depth` is 2

In other words, you are requesting that all child headlines of `Document Structure` (up to a depth of 2) be numbered (using overlay)

***Number all child headlines of `Document Structure` up to level 2***
[image: Number all child headlines up to level 2]